# How to rewrite a file before publish based on build configuration?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, asp.net-core-mvc, gulp-replace

I have a new asp.net V5 application that is really just a static angular site and I'm trying to do the equivalent of web.config transforms.  My app.js file has a constant defined that is the serviceUrl which points to the url of our api (not in the same site)

I've used gulp-replace and created tasks for each of our build targets that successfully replace the single string that needs to be replaced.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to change that service url based on the build configuration that is chosen so that we can automate deploys etc. and not have to change that url for each different target. (i.e. dev goes to devapi.xxx.com and release goes to https://api.xxx.com etc.)

I've found the prepublish scripts section, but it doesn't seem to allow me to be specific based on the configuration. And the configurations section doesn't seem to allow me to specify scripts that will run.

So my question is, how does one do a pre-publish step that finds and replaces that string contextually based on the configuration?

Comment: OK that would work but I don't know how I'd update a js file with that  information so have the js file load that somehow?  There's no mvc here so I can't inject it from mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Working with Multiple Environments](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html).

Basically, your `appsettings.json` is what you are looking for. In your `Startup.cs` you should have a line that kinda look like this:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

By default, in Visual Studio, the `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable will be set to `Development`. When not run by Visual Studio, it will default to `Production`.

So by definition, when running your app in production it will automatically override `appsettings.json` values with `appsettings.Production.json`.

That file will of course be optional and could be kept by your IT department with all the precious passwords inside of it.

If you are storing passwords and connnection strings however, I would highly recommend reading about [Safe Storage of Application Secrets](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html).

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how I'd get that into the js file unless you're saying that on the publish script that has already been exchanged and I can just load it in gulp and read the value out?

Comment: You could generate a JSON containing your URLs. Deserialzes pretty well. :-)

Comment: Right but how do I do it contextually based on the build configuration?  I can't tell in gulp what the build config is, and I can't inject that as far as I can tell?

Comment: Check gulp and environment variable. There's a package to retrieve it since it's `ASPNET_ENV` or `Production `. You can read the JSON file anyway since you'll be in gulp.

Comment: Thanks!  Any pointers on how to get the environment variable in gulp?

Comment: Good tutorial right there: http://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/10/13/gulp-gulpfile-environment-variable/

Comment: This won't work because I can't set the environment variable based on the build configuration set. (i.e. I can't set TFS using the same build resources to one time use the QA build configuration and thus the QA envionrment variable and then the next time use the Release build configuration and have gulp execute based on what TFS is building. Nor can I do this directly in VS.net because it's per machine not per build configuration which is the issue.)

Comment: Why do you need a compile time variable? The whole process relies on having the configuration being dynamic and when the variable change, it just loads a different file.

Comment: Because I'm not using mvc. I need to replace a URL in JavaScript before publishing so my static angular site knows what URL to use to talk to the api.  Hence gulp needs to know build config and or publishing target so that it knows what to replace. I don't want the overhead of mvc just to put in one URL.

Comment: MVC uses Environment Variables to determine that. Those can be also accessed with Gulp.

Comment: Again not using mvc. Need to get the build config that the publish is acting up during gulp pre publish task so I can rewrite. If it's possible to get that please share. Otherwise this is a huge oversight for anyone doing angular.

Comment: The environment selection is not in the build configuration itself. The only reason it's available is because the devenv process will actually set `ASPNET_ENV` before executing DNX (and gulp by the same thread). So the only thing left (if you want to do multiple-builds with gulp) is to run the gulp command but set the `ASPNET_ENV` before hand.

Comment: That's my point. I can't find any way to do this conditionally based in publish profile or build config and thus my deploys have to be manual as a result of this oversight.

Comment: To be specific, I'm saying that the environment variables need to be specific to build configuration in the ui in vs.net and set accordingly just like compiler directives can be.